# Change public folder in vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I run `npm run build` I get the following error message.

> [copy-webpack-plugin] unable to locate 'path\to\project\public' at 'path\to\project\public'

I moved the `public` folder to `src/main/resources/public`. However I can't find a config to change the path. I think the relevant code is in `node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\app.js`

```
// copy static assets in public/
webpackConfig
  .plugin('copy')
    .use(require('copy-webpack-plugin'), [[{
      from: api.resolve('public'),
      to: api.resolve(options.outputDir),
      ignore: ['index.html', '.DS_Store']
    }]])
```

How do I override this in vue.config.js?

Comment: You should simply take a look at your `webpack.config.json` file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me using vue-cli 3.0.  Just add it to your vue.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        return [{template: '/path/to/index.html'}]
      })
  }
}
```

Though this might be more technically correct.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0] = {
            template: '/path/to/index.html'
        }
        return args
      })
  }
}
```

Edit:

Actually this would be the preferred way of doing this so that none of the other defaults are overwritten.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].template = '/path/to/index.html'
        return args
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but path has to start with `./` otherwise you get some error `module could not be resolved` so `./path/to/index.html`